# Programming ADC

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

I have written a code for ADC for s12x microcontroller. My doubt is the datasheet tells me to check for hardware flag to be set to know that conversion is complete.To know this I have used infinite while loop. Most of the time it works but found an instance while random testing that the code stays in infinite loop in this while loop. Is it bad programming to put while loop in embedded programming? Should I find out the reason why at one instant while loop failed or i can neglect it.

Answer (score 1):

You surely don't need an answer to the 'can I neglect it?' question?

When your ADC fails for whatever reason, would you rather have your system hang, or produce a message saying 'ADC failed **again** at time=xx, params=yyy, config=zzzz'. The latter might give you a chance of finding out what's wrong, or at the very least retry the operation.

Rather than loop forever, it's slightly more sanitary to loop while waiting_time:less_than:some_limit. Then if the time expires, you know you have your ADC setup wrong somehow, and you can tidily dump what you were expecting it to do and recover.

Comment: One of the constant question always goes in my mind. When we are dealing with hardware flags I feel very little we can do to debug the issue.

Comment: What you can do is mirror the hardware flags on to some spare i/o pins in your while loop (unless that resets the flags) then you can monitor the flags with a scope or even an LED.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your overall design.  If the whole point of this code is to take those measurements and process it.  Then if the adc fails to convert or fails in general then the code has failed anyway so what if it is hung in a loop.  If the failures are encountering are something that the software can recover from by trying again.  And the system design can tolerate a missed sample without declaring a total failure, then put a timeout in there and try again.

Hanging code in basically an infinite loop using fork() is a very common practice in applications running on operating systems.  Can be as well here.

This is why you have a watch dog timer, to recover from hangs.  maybe you dont want to hang by design, but maybe you do.  the early lirc PIC code relied on the wdt to reset it by design.

If there is no recovery path, then the timeout becomes a suicide note.  Instead of just dying you get to leave a suicide note then shoot yourself in the head.  End result dead anyway.  Is the suicide note worth the extra code and development?  every line of code adds risk to your design.

so answer is "it depends"...

Comment: you should put some effort into understanding why it is not completing the conversion every time in a lab situation...

Comment: lean on the chip vendors tech support once you have a small-ish example that creates the problem in a reasonable amount of time.